# Distributed JMeter test fails with java error but test will run from JMeter UI (non-distributed)

Tags: jmeter

My goal is to run a load test using 4 Azure servers as load generators and 1 Azure server to initiate the test and gather results. I had the distributed test running and I was getting good data. But today when I remote start the test 3 of the 4 load generators fail with all the http transactions erroring. The failed transactions log the following error:

> Non HTTP response message: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jFactory (Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jFactory)

I confirmed the presence of commons-logging-1.2.jar in the jmeter\lib folder on each machine.

To try to narrow down the issue I set up one Azure server to both initiate the load and run JMeter-server but this fails too. However, if I start the test from the JMeter UI on that same server the test runs OK. I think this rules out a problem in the script or a problem with the Azure machines talking to each other.

I also simplified my test plan down to where it only runs one simple http transaction and this still fails.

I've gone through all the basics: reinstalled jmeter, updated java to the latest version (1.8.0_111), updated the JAVA_HOME environment variable and backed out the most recent Microsoft Security update on the server. Any advice on how to pick this problem apart would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using JMeter 3.0r1743807 and Java 1.8
The Azure servers are running Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

I did get a resolution to this problem. It turned out to be a conflict between some extraneous code in a jar file and a component of JMeter. It was “spooky” because something influenced the load order of referenced jar files and JMeter components.

I had included a jar file in my JMeter script using the “Add directory or jar to classpath” function in the Test Plan. This jar file has a piece of code I needed for my test along with many other components and one of those components, probably a similar logging function, conflicted with a logging function in JMeter. The problem was spooky; the test ran fine for months but started failing at the maximally inconvenient time. The problem was revealed by creating a very simple JMeter test that would load and run just fine. If I opened the simple test in JMeter then, without closing JMeter, opened my problem test, my problem test would not fail. If I reversed the order, opening the problem test followed by the simple test then the simple test would fail too. Given that the problem followed the order in which things loaded I started looking at the jar files and found my suspect.

When I built the script I left the jar file alone thinking that the functions I need might have dependencies to other pieces within the jar. Now that things are broken I need to find out if that is true and happily it is not. So, to fix the problem I changed the extension on my jar file to zip then edited it in 7-zip. I removed all the code except what I needed. I kept all the folders in the path to my needed code, I did this for two reasons; I did not have to update my code that called the functions and when I tried changing the path the functions did not work.

Next I changed the extension on the file back to jar and changed the reference in JMeter’s “Add directory or jar to classpath” function to point to the revised jar. I haven’t seen the failure since.

Many thanks to the folks who looked at this. I hope the resolution will help someone out.